# Using `ip address show type` to display physical network interface

Tags: linux-networking, ip

Using Ubuntu 20.04. I have learnt in [How to get only the name of the physical ethernet interface?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432251/140949) that to display only the physical network interfaces, we could do

```
ls -l /sys/class/net/ | grep -v virtual
```

I tried (unsuccessfully) to obtain the same info using `ip address show type XXX`. According to `ip address help` the possible types are:

```
TYPE := { vlan | veth | vcan | vxcan | dummy | ifb | macvlan | macvtap |
          bridge | bond | ipoib | ip6tnl | ipip | sit | vxlan | lowpan |
          gre | gretap | erspan | ip6gre | ip6gretap | ip6erspan | vti |
          nlmon | can | bond_slave | ipvlan | geneve | bridge_slave |
          hsr | macsec | netdevsim }
```

Q1. Is it possible to use `ip address` to show only the physical interfaces? For example, to see the local IP addresses of the machine.

Q2. Maybe there is a good reason for not having a type corresponding to physical interface. What is the rationale?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The interface type is more a *link* property than an *address* property even if this information can be available (but not always) in `ip address`'s output. So the command to use to answer the *title* of OP's question would be `ip link show`...

...but an hardware interface has no type associated. Only the virtual interfaces get this simply because it's an *additional property* that doesn't have a real interface (this answers Q2, but see note at the end). So there's no type allowing to display the physical ones, and as there's no negation available in the filter options either (nor an expression to display *any* type to negate upon), there's no filter available in the command syntax to display *only* such interfaces.

To find those interfaces, you must display all of them, and filter out those without type with an external filter. So what can't be done with the `ip link` command alone, can be done by filtering its output, with an adequate tool: [`jq`](https://manpages.debian.org/jq/jq.1) using `ip -details -json link`'s JSON output, for reliable parsing. There's this [`jq` documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) to learn how to use it, the man page is based on its contents.

From the full list of interface this has to be done:

- exclude any type found (in the JSON output that's the *info_kind* property of the *linkinfo*, which can be all of the type from the help (*vlan*, *veth*, ...), not to be confused with *link_type* which can be for example *loopback*,  *ether*, *none* ...).
- exclude the loopback *link_type*.

which translates into:

```
ip -details -json link show | jq -r '
.[] | 
      if .linkinfo.info_kind // .link_type == "loopback" then
          empty
      else
          .ifname
      end
'
```

For example, on this system with currently a total of 12 interfaces, only those two, the only two real, are displayed with the command above:

```
eth0
wlan0
```

Fell free to improve this *jq* filter.

To address question Q1, for this case, replacing `ip ... link` with `ip ... address` will give the same output. But to display the addresses in addition to the interfaces, of course the filter has to change (and requires a recent enough `jq` command to allow custom handling of linefeeds):

```
ip -details -json address show | jq --join-output '
.[] | 
      if .linkinfo.info_kind // .link_type == "loopback" then
          empty
      else
          .ifname ,
          ( ."addr_info"[] |
              if .family == "inet" or .family == "inet6" then
                  " " + .local
              else
                  empty
              end
          ),
          "\n"
      end
'
```

If you want to check the whole JSON output directly, try `ip -details -pretty -json address` or `ip -d -j address | jq .`. The `-json` option is available for several *iproute2* commands, but not all of them. Its addition for the `ip ...` commands is quite recent ([mid 2017](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/commit/?h=v4.14.0&id=5df607725928d532a3b7e5095c04e943b2c3ce7f)).

---

Note: actually the `type` keyword can translate to multiple different types of properties when used in JSON: `.linkinfo.info_kind` is the actual type of interface as described before, but there is also `.linkinfo.info_slave_kind` for an interface (including a real interface) that has a bridge or a bond as master (resp. `bridge_slave` and `bond_slave`). This won't change JSON results since it won't check this property.

Anyway such interfaces should never have an IP address set to them then: the address should be set to the master, which despite being virtual, should be the interface that matters when interacting with the physical environment around.

Comment: Very neat workaround and I confirm it is working on Ubuntu 20.04 + microk8s + Docker. On this machine `ip address` returns ~40 addresses. And yet your script is abe to find exactly the two physical network interfaces AND the associated IP4 IPv6 addresses.Also learnt a few tricks about `jq` in the process. Expert workaround, thanks.

Comment: "but an hardware interface has no type associated. Only the virtual interfaces get this simply because ..." I am not expert in linux networking. But I am not totally convinced by the rationale. The fact that you (and maybe everybody else?) call it "hardware (or physical) interface" hints that filter to this type of interface is a real need. And should desserve a dedicated interface type of the same stature than `vlan` `veth`, etc. Matbe just create a new type and name it `physical`? Would it be acceptable as a feature request to `ip` maintainers?

Comment: I hope than one of the kernel maintainers would read this post. Because I would be unable to formulate a sensible feature request that make sense in terms of inner working mechanics of the kernel as you have explained. From the end user point of view the need is simply "use ip to return hardware interface and their associated IP addresses". If such high level request is acceptable, can you show me how/where to submit the request to the kernel maintainers team?

Comment: No idea how to do this properly. There's the MAINTAINERS file in the linux source to check, but it might be reserved for devlopment (eg: if you submitted a patch for what you're asking). There's also https://bugzilla.kernel.org/ but you want a new feature, that's not really a bug.